# prependTo using with variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I work with jquery 1.3.2. I have created a variable pointing to an image. I would like to duplicate this image on the same position.

In code I use selector http://jsfiddle.net/Z7Pry/101/

```
var image = closestwrap.find('img');
$(image).clone().prependTo("#contentWrapRight")
```

but I need to use variable "image" in order to match and duplicate exactly certain image on the same position. This does not work

```
$(image).clone().prependTo(image)
```

What should I do to achieve this functionality? Thank you.

Comment: This seems to work. Maybe you should be more precise. And please, upgrade jQuery, many bugs were fixed since this version.

Comment: `img` elements cannot have children, that's why you cannot append or prepend any element to it.

Comment: @dystroy I do not understand what seems to work. After submitting button, I need the images to start from where they are in html. Now they start from one place.

Comment: `"I need the images to start from where they are in html"`. Well. It's more clear if you say what you want...

Comment: @FelixKling Should I use a wrapper around the image to make it work?

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for `$(image).clone().before(image)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `prependTo` use [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore) or [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter).

```
$(image).clone().insertBefore(image);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Z7Pry/102/

---

Use `productX` and `productY` as the initial position, and `basketX` and `basketY` as the final position of the animation..

Comment: @user1031743 (as you might have noted in the fiddle i meant to use `insertBefore(image)` .. (*updated answer*)

Answer (score 0):

To give a correct start position, change the call to `css` :

```
    $(image).clone().prependTo("#contentWrapRight").css({
        'position': 'fixed',
        left: productX, top: productY, 'z-index': '999'
```

<kbd>**[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/gu2cS/)**</kbd>

Note that you can change all your `$(image)` to simply `image` as `image` is already a jQuery object.